# Persistent Menu POST Success but not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I hope this isnt a duplicate question, I couldnt find anything that was the same as this so I thought I would post..

I'm trying to push a persistent menu to my FB page at the moment, im Posting from POSTMAN with the following code:

```
  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"persistent_menu":[
    {
    "locale":"default",
    "composer_input_disabled":true,
    "call_to_actions":[
        {
        "title":"Info",
        "type":"nested",
        "call_to_actions":[
            {
            "title":"web_url",
            "type":"postback",
            "payload":"http://www.techiediaries.com"
            },
            {
            "title":"web_url",
            "type":"postback",
            "payload":"http://www.techiediaries.com"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "type":"web_url",
        "title":"Visit website ",
        "url":"http://www.techiediaries.com",
        "webview_height_ratio":"full"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "locale":"en_US",
    "composer_input_disabled":false
    }
]
}'
```

This action is returning **{"result": "success"}**, however on my FB page I cant see any change to my messenger, ive also tried deleting the conversation and restarting (as per the FB messenger Documentation) but this still does not provide a result.

Is there something im doing wrong or overlooking?

Many thanks,

Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being caused because the second object in your array doesn't specify a button:

```
{
  "locale":"en_US",
  "composer_input_disabled":false
}
```

This should return a syntax error, but is currently failing silently. I'll report it.

Answer (score 0):

As amuramoto wrote, it is problably because you don't offer any call_to_actions (buttons) for the locale en_US and you are using en_US. You could test it with another locale, like en_UK or use a spanish facebook account for testing.

Yet this is not a bug. As the doc states: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/persistent-menu?locale=en_US

call_to_actions ---- Array < menu_item > ---- 
*An array of top-level menu items for the persistent menu. A maximum of 3 items is allowed. A maximum of two nested menus are supported.*

**Required if "composer_input_disabled": true.**
Which is not the case in your example. Your setting is meant to be used for "no buttons, but free typing".